# How to apply patch/put rest api for kubernetes Pod env variables

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to use Patch and Put API to modify the podspec, I am able to update container images version with both Patch and Put API.
But I am not able to modify the Env variables for pod, I want to update Env variables, Can you please help here. Attached is the image[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do and what's actually happening without the code, logs and/or error messages. Please consider adding them.

Comment: In most cases you can't edit Pods, only delete and recreate them.  You shouldn't usually directly use Pods; a higher-level object like a Deployment is generally a better choice.

Comment: How do you update container image versions via Patch and PUT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patching Pod may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations).

Env variables are immutable for pods because this information is set when the pod gets created. So what you need is only achievable using a Deployment instead of a Pod.

When you update a env variable in a Deployment, all pods will be recreated to make changes happen.

An easier method to set/change variables is to make use of [kubectl set env](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-env-em-).

```
kubectl set env deployment/test LOG_LEVEL=ERROR
```

Comment: kubectl set env pod/test LOG_LEVEL=ERROR     This doe not work. Can we not change pod env variable?

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation why it doesn't work for pods.

Comment: I got this below error:     error: failed to patch env update to pod template: Pod "test" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)

Comment: Yes, this happens because you are trying to patch a pod and as I explained in my answer you need to use a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) in place of just a Pod.

Comment: ok, kubectl replace -f testPod.yaml --force  This command works and replaces all the modified content of Pod. For Replace, PUT rest api is used. what parameter i need to pass to do force replace for PUT restapi